# Помощь с ботом aiogram python

Tags: python, aiogram

я хочу отвечать на сообщения через бота(reply), бот присылает мне сообщения в приватный чат, от пользователя, я отвечаю ему через reply, и бот должен отправить сообщение, как это сделать ? (python aiogram) Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Незачто........

Answer (score -1):

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
bot = Bot(token="тут токен вашего бота")
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

idsm = "" 
to_id = "" #сюда пишите ваш айди
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def func(message: types.Message):
    await message.forward(to_id) # пересылка сообщения вам
    idsm=message.from_user.id # id пользователя того кто пишет вам


@dp.message_handler(commands=['send'])
async def send(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=idsm, text=(message.text).split('/send ')[1]) # отправка вашего сообщения обратно пользователю
```

чтобы начать общение пользователь пишет `/start` и свое сообщение например `/start привет!`
и вы ему отвечаете `/send и тебе привет!` и ему приходит `и тебе привет!`

Я надеюсь вам помог, если это так то оцените сообщение